# Uglify one JS file using requirejs optimizer

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, uglifyjs

I'd like to know if there is a way to uglify only one file in command line using r.js (RequireJS Optimizer) which is already installed in my computer.
Like we can minify a css file using `node r.js cssIn="" out=""` ...

I'm actually working from a computer without internet connection, I'm not able to install something else on it (especially using npm)

Maybe is there a possibility to download an uglifyjs package from another computer including all dependencies ready to be installed on mine? I didn't find something like that though...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Copy uglify from another computer

Since you mentioned this as a possibility in your question, I'm going to cover it.

#### First method

1. On the computer that has `uglify-js`. Find where `uglify-js` is installed. Archive that directory and its subdirectories.
2. On the disconnected computer. Unarchive that directory in a `node_modules` subdirectory for your project. Let's suppose the project is in `/home/johndoe/foo`. I would want to unarchive it in `/home/johndoe/foo/node_modules`.
3. You can use `uglify-js` at `node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglify-js`.

This first method is the method I would use.

#### Second method

If somehow the first method does not work for you or does not work well, there's a second method. The fact is that copying installed Node packages does not perfectly replicate the installation process. In may cases it may work perfectly but in some cases it may not. So here's a method that makes `npm` go through the whole installation process.

1. On the computer where uglify is installed, do:

   ```
   $ npm ls
   ```

   In the output look for uglify-js and all the packages that are *inside* it hierarchically. The output will look like this:

   ```
   ├── cookie@0.1.0
   ├─┬ uglify-js@2.4.12
   │ ├── async@0.2.10
   │ ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
   │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
   │ ├─┬ source-map@0.1.31
   │ │ └── amdefine@0.1.0
   │ └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
   └── yaml@0.2.3
   ```

   In the output above you care about `uglify-js` up to and including `uglify-to-browserify`. For each of these packages, look into npm's cache for the compressed package file. On Linux and similar systems this will be in `~/.npm/`. For instance, on my machine `uglify-js` is cached at `~/.npm/uglify-js/2.4.12/package.tgz`. Copy each of these packages to media that you can take to the disconnected computer. Make sure that you copy the correct versions. They are listed after the `@` sign in the listing above.
2. Move the media to your disconnected computer.
3. For each package install it with:

   ```
   $ npm install [path to the tgz file]
   ```

   When you pass a `tgz` to `npm` it ignores the network, so long as all dependencies are met. The order here is important. You want to start with packages that have no dependencies themselves. I beleive the way `npm ls` produces its list, if you just go in reverse order you'll be okay. So:

   - amdefine
   - source-map
   - wordrap
   - optimist
   - async
   - uglify-js

   At the end of this process the `uglifyjs` command will be in `node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs`. You can readily test it against one of `uglifyjs`' own files. For instance:

   ```
   $ node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs node_modules/uglify-js/lib/output.js
   ```

I've tried a few other methods but found that `npm` is quite eager to go to the network to find packages. It's really easy to think "maybe ABC would work..." and find that it does not because even though everything is available locally, `npm` **still** wants a network connection.

### Using the `uglify-js` included in `r.js`

The `r.js` optimizer include s `uglify-js` in it. Unfortunately, it is not packaged to be trivially usable outside `r.js`. However, you can access it like this:

```
var r = require("./node_modules/.bin/r.js");
var fs = require("fs");

var config = {};

var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]).toString();

r.tools.useLib("mine", function (require) {
    require(["uglifyjs/index"], function (uglify) {
        var parser = uglify.parser;
        var processor = uglify.uglify;

        var ast = parser.parse(fileContents, config.strict_semicolons);
        if (config.no_mangle !== true) {
            ast = processor.ast_mangle(ast, config);
        }
        ast = processor.ast_squeeze(ast, config);

        fileContents = processor.gen_code(ast, config);

        if (config.max_line_length) {
            fileContents = processor.split_lines(fileContents,
                                                 config.max_line_length);
        }

        //Add trailing semicolon to match uglifyjs command line version
        fileContents += ';';

        fs.writeFileSync(process.argv[3], fileContents);
    });
});
```

If the above code is saved in a file named `script.js` and invoked like this `node script.js input output`, it will uglify `input` and put the result in `output`. The key is to use the `tools.useLib` method exported by `r.js`. This allows access to the libraries that `r.js` includes. The rest of the code is mostly copied from the section in `r.js` where it performs uglification.

### Use `r.js` at the command line

```
$ r.js -o name=main exclude=main out=built.js
```

This would optimize only the module `main` (in the file `main.js`) and put the output in `build.js`. It won't follow any dependencies of `main`. However, it modifies the `define` by adding the module's name as the first parameter. This could be removed with a post-processing step with `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, etc.

If the file you want to uglify would be shimmed for use with RequireJS (not an actual AMD-style module), you don't want to use the `exclude` parameter:

```
$ r.js -o name=shimmed out=built.js
```

Just like the first command above, this also does more than just uglify the file. It adds a `define` call at the end. Again, this could be taken out with `sed` or a similar tool.

(I've definitely been able to use these commands without `baseUrl=.`. However, depending on what you do exactly, `r.js` may complain. So you may have to add `baseUrl=.` to the command line.)

Answer (score 0):

put the file in a folder

run r.js from inside that folder:

```
node r.js -o baseUrl=. name=main out=main-built.js
```

you do not have an internet connection on that computer, isnt it just easyer to put the file on something like an usb sitck and uglify it on a computer that has internet?

Comment: This is not working. My javascript files contain dependencies to other files, when I extract the file alone in a folder and execute the command, it's trying to track dependencies, which are not in the folder of course.

Comment: if its just this once, add the deps one path below? eg. require('../file')

Answer (score 0):

I'll address how you can copy over a node package directly from one computer, because with this trick you'll have uglify, or clean-css or whatever package you want.

The background is that a node package includes copies of all its dependencies underneath its own install directory - this makes it easy to grab an entire package by a simple `cp -r` or `xcopy` if you're on Windows (which I don't claim to support)

Assuming one computer has an install of the `clean-css` package

`which cleancss`

should show a path such as `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/cleancss`, in which case you'll want to recursively copy `/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/clean-css/` over to the other machine's corresponding node_modules folder (creating a symlink in `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/` as well) to have access to that without the internet.